# RabbitMq listener listening to two different message types on two different queues

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

My requirement is to be able to listen to rabbitMq messages on two different queues. One queue receives message with content_type = text/plain and my Spring boot listener method accepts String parameter. Second queue receives message with content_type = application/json and my listener method accepts parameter of my POJO 'User' type. I am sending messages using RabbitMQ web portal. I am not able to successfully listen to both types of messages in the same spring boot listener application. Please help me to succeed in listening to both types of messages on two queues.Below is my listener class and configuraiton class code snippet.

Listener class:

```
@Component
public class EventListener {

    public void processFirstQueue(String message) {
        try {
            if (message != null) {
                log.info("Received the message from Queue!");
                service.process(message);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error occurred " + e);
        }
    }
    
    public void processSecondQueue(User user) {
        try {
            if (user!= null) {
                log.info("Received the message from Queue!");
                service.processUser(user);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error occurred " + e);
        }
    }
}

RabbitMqConfig.java
public class RabbitMqConfig {
    
    @Bean(name = "rabbitmq-server")
    public CachingConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        cachingConnectionFactory.setHost("localhost");
        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }
            
    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames("queue1", "queue2");
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        container.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(OutgoingEventListener receiver) {
        MessageListenerAdapter listener = new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver);
        Map<String, String> queueToMethodName = new HashMap<>();
        queueToMethodName.put("queue1", "processFirstQueue");
        queueToMethodName.put("queue2", "processSecondQueue");
        listener.setQueueOrTagToMethodName(queueToMethodName);
        return listener;
    }
     @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
    
     @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate getRabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }
    
}
```

I am able to post json message successfully to queue2 as seen in below screenshot.

[image]

But when I am posting content_type = text/plain to queue1 as seen in below screenshot, I am getting error in my Spring boot service saying content-type text is found but json is expected.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add message converter for your consumer like that -

```
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
 
@Configuration
public class RabbitMqConfig {
  
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter(){
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory jsaFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        factory.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting this error while posting json message to second queue org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to invoke target method 'processSecondEvent' with argument type = [class [B], value = [{[B@16f7a312}]

Comment: try this https://www.cuba-platform.com/discuss/t/background-service-to-receive-messages-from-amqp-messagebroker-rabbitmq/2624/2

Comment: It explained good. Thanks .But for me one method should accept String and one method should accept json as POJO class instance. I am not able to do both types of methods in one listener. Only one type is working. If I use Jackson2JsonMessageConverter in the SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory bean i am able to read as POJO directly using @RabbitListener above my processSecondQueuemethod.  But processFirstQueueMethod is not working and error is found content-type = text/plain where json is expected.

Comment: Error while sending json message from rabbitmq portal with content_type = text/plain for first queue is  "Could not convert incoming message with content-type [text/plain], 'json' keyword missing." First queue processing method accepts String type message. Second queue I am sending Json using content_type = application/json and it is working fine.

Comment: For first queue I used Message type for input message and it is working for both queues now.

Comment: @ajjusadda Please accept, vote to answer so that It can be helpful for others aswell, thanks.